# javascript - how to handle asynchronous function inside if block

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sequelize.js

for the following pseudocode

```
var variable = value1
if(condition)
{
    sequelize.query().then({ variable = result })
}
sequelize.query(queryBuilder(variable))
```

the second sequelize query keeps executing after the first one inside the if block. how to hold execution inside the if block until the query inside it is done?

Comment: The if block is nothing to do with it, the same thing would happen without it.

Comment: If you want to keep the appearence of sequential execution use async/await syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
const intermediatePromise = condition
    ? sequelize.query().then({ variable = result })
    : Promise.resolve();

intermediatePromise.then(// moving on
```